# R: How do I filter a named list on names present in a vector?

Tags: r, list, subset

I am trying to obtain a subset of a named list, based on element present in another list.

```
nammedlist<-list( "a"=c(1,2,3,4), "b"=c(2,4,5), "c"=c(9,5,3,2))

selection<-c("a","c")
```

desired output:

```
namedlist2<-list( "a"=c(1,2,3,4), "c"=c(9,5,3,2))
```

I am considering writing a for loop checking for each name if it is present and then extracting it. But their must be a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the names as an index:

```
nammedlist[selection]
```

will give you what you want.

Note that you use single brackets, not double brackets.  Single brackets mean that you want a subset of the list.  Double brackets mean you want to extract an element from the list.

Comment: Can add `intersect()` for *"checking for each name if it is present"* `nammedlist[intersect(names(nammedlist), selection)]`

Comment: @sindri_baldur:  Yes, if `selection` contains a name that isn't found, you get an ugly entry named `NA` in the result if you use my code, so using `intersect()` would be a good idea.